# How to run a class each time when there is a change in another class?

Tags: java

Consider the following code:

```
public class UserJMXBeanExpose{
private UserJMXBeanImpl userJMXBean;


public UserJMXBeanExpose(UserJMXBeanImpl userJMXBean) {
    this.userJMXBean = userJMXBean;
}

public void init() throws MBeanRegistrationException, InstanceAlreadyExistsException, NotCompliantMBeanException, MalformedObjectNameException {

    MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("MineStar:type=UserJMXBeanExpose,name=Statistics");
    MineStarMBean impl = new MineStarMBean();

    impl.addProperty(new PropertyAdapter("User", "User List", "java.lang.String") {
        public Object getValue() {
            if (userJMXBean == null) return 0;
            return userJMXBean.getUserAttributes();
        }
    });

    server.registerMBean(impl, objectName);
}

}
```

And this code:

```
public class UserJMXBeanImpl implements UserJMXBean {

private  List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

public void addUser(User user){
    userList.add(user);

}

public List<User> getUserList() {
      return userList;
}

public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
    this.userList = userList;
}

public String[] getUserAttributes(){
    for(User user : this.getUserList()){
            return new String[]{user.getUserId(),user.getRoles()};
}
    return null;
}

}
```

When a user logs in the the class userjmxbeanimpl stores the data. But I need to activate the userjmxbeanexpose class too as soon as a new user is added so that it can expose the data grabbed from impl class. How can I do this? 
The spring configuration goes like this:

```
<bean id="userJMXBeans" class="minestar.platform.domain.user.UserJMXBeanExpose" init-method="init" scope="singleton"
      lazy-init="false">
    <constructor-arg ref="userJMXBean"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern ?

Comment: Can anybody help me with listeners in java for this code? How should I implement it?

Comment: Hmm... Wait - is the part `When a user logs in the the class userjmxbeanimpl stores the data` working already?

Comment: @Deltharis Yes, the user who logs in gets stored in userjmxbeanimpl's userList. I have debugged and seen it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what logic it would represent, but judging by the code you provided... The only thing you need to do to make it *work* is to do:

```
public void addUser(User user){
   userList.add(user);
   new UserJMXBeanExpose(this).init();
}
```

After consideration Observer pattern doesn't seem to work here, it would be a lot of boilerplate code that would essentially do the same and bring no benefits. Unless I misunderstood what it means to `activate UserJMXBeanExpose`.

Comment: Will try this and let you know soon.

Comment: It is giving javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException exception as  scope="singleton". Doing it prototype is also not working.

Comment: So init can be called only once. Ok, so I don't know what it means to activate it, nor when it should be done.

Comment: How can I add listener to it?

Comment: Listener, regardless of implementation, would need to have something to DO when it sees stuff happening. What it should do is "activate UserJMXBeanExpose" (by your words). I don't know what that means I'm afraid/

Comment: I meant fire the 'UserJMXBeanExpose' class as soon as a new userList is generated.